# Typescript Return anything but Promise

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to specify a function type that can return anything but a Promise?

My interface looks like this:

```
interface AnInterface {
    func(): AllowAnythingButAPromise;
}
```

I tried:

```
type AllowAnythingButAPromise<T> = T extends Exclude<any, Promise<any>> ? T: never;
type AllowAnythingButAPromise<T> = T extends Exclude<any, Promise<unknown>> ? T: never;
type AllowAnythingButAPromise<T> = T extends Promise<unknown> ? never : T;
type AllowAnythingButAPromise<T> = T extends Promise<any> ? never : T;


type anything = number | symbol | string | boolean | null | undefined | object | Function;
type AllowAnythingButAPromise<T> = T extends Exclude<anything, Function> ? T: never;
```

With no luck so far... Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a supported way to do negated types. There are various work arounds to get some use cases to work.

In your case, I would opt for a return type that is a union of primitive types and an object type where the `then` property is optional and typed as undefined, ensuring nothing with a `then` property is assignable to the return type. This might carve out a bit more than you like, but it might be an acceptable compromise.

```
interface AnInterface {
    func(): number | boolean | string| symbol | { then?: never, [n: string]: unknown };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIgJLmvJyDeAsAFDJnIwCuICAFAJQBcyIlAtgEbTIA+yHAewEAbCHBC9kAZzBRQAcz5SAnpxGT8yMAAsIIAPzNqAEwgxQEYwBpkAbRDMZckPIC6RkAGsQAgO4SAXwBuEgCSBGE4KSlkABUIGQAFOTZgMGAANwTkYDYAB1E2PTAY9CxIWEQUIlJyKhoGAhJyFuQoCDBKKAkARhDasjDiIYiomPiZAHkOACsyXIKIIvBSzGxKvBqW+rp6JoHW9s7ugmQ4ZlZhYWRg5vIhkcjouISwACE4Yxz8wuLV8pwVX2LSiyhoFGou2BrTIRy6Ek052QPRu-RaDxIJFEYGQAh6zDK61wKAAvNCyDtGlsYW0OvDkXdBqFMcRsbiAEwEtYVYnIMnUsig8GUvYCw50k49Rk3ZnELEdXEAZi5AI2pPJEIaoulLThJ00MCEzBRQ3RoSAA)